# How to set the usercontrol for ribbon window in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

First I've created a WPF application, then I added new RibbonWindows to the application, and called it RibbonWindow1. Now I want to set the content of the ribbon control via the code belowe and show the ribbon:

```
 RibbonWindow1 ribWindow = new RibbonWindow1
            {
                Title = "This is a ribbon window",
                Content = new UserControl1()
            };
            ribWindow.ShowDialog();
```

But I can't see the ribbon bar. If I remove content the ribbon will be shown, also if I use drag and drop I can show it, but I want to do it via simple code, dynamically.
If I can dock the related control in a specific grid cell it will be helpful to me. Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot add controls to a ribbon window, you need to add them to a RibbonGroup within a RibbonTab.

Comment: Would u explain what u saying about? as i can see ribbon group doesn't have any property to set for it, and if u use drag and drop the control will be dropped into the Grid of RibbonWindow not in the related item of RibbonGroup or ribbontab.

Answer (score 0):

In my little experience with RibbonWindow, i saw that ribbon is part of the content of the ribbonwindow itself. So, a solution could be to expose a public method for the ribbon window that set your usercontrol, like this:

```
<ribbon:RibbonWindow ...>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ribbon:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon" />
    //add a container for your usercontrol
    <Grid Name="contentPlaceHolder" Grid.Row="1"></Grid>   
 </Grid>
```

and in the code you can set a method like

```
public void SetControl(UserControl uc)
{
   this.contentPlaceHolder.Content = uc; 
}
```

Comment: Hi michele, sorry for late response, currently I'm not working on this, first time I switched, I'll read your answer :)

Comment: Can you provide a piece of your code where you have this problem? Maybe XAML + code would be more descriptive ;)