# Use a UserControl inside a Ribbon

Tags: wpf, user-controls, ribbon

I want to use a UserControl inside a RibbonControl.

For example:

```
<RibbonWindow
  xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:UserControl1;assembly=UserControl1">

  <Grid ShowGridLines="False" Margin="0">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100*"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
     </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

     <Ribbon Grid.Row="0">
        <RibbonApplicationMenu >
          <RibbonApplicationMenuItem x:Name="miExit" ImageSource="Images/large_exit.png" Header="Exit" />
        </RibbonApplicationMenu>
        <RibbonTab Header="Test">
            <uc:RibbonGroups/>
        </RibbonTab>
     </Ribbon>

     <uc:Content Grid.Row="1" />

  </Grid>

</RibbonWindow>
```

You see two UserControls, uc:RibbonGroups and uc:Content. While the second one (uc:Content) works fine, the UserControl inside the RibbonControl won't work.

What i missed? 
I also try this approach:
[How to set the usercontrol for ribbon window in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921934/how-to-set-the-usercontrol-for-ribbon-window-in-wpf)
an set a grid inside the RibbonTab and then the UserControl;

```
     <Ribbon Grid.Row="0">
         ...
        <Grid>
        <RibbonTab Header="Test">
            <uc:RibbonGroups/>
        </RibbonTab>
        </Grid>
     </Ribbon>
```

instead of

```
     <Ribbon Grid.Row="0">
         ...
        <RibbonTab Header="Test">
            <uc:RibbonGroups/>
        </RibbonTab>
     </Ribbon>
```

**Edit:**
UserControl now only holds the content of RibbonTab, RibbonTab itself moved to the main window

```
  <UserControl ...>
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <RibbonGroup Header="Test" >
             <RibbonButton SmallImageSource="Images/small_save.png"
                           LargeImageSource="Images/large_save.png" />
        <Image Source="Images/large_expert_enabled.png"></Image>
     </Stackpanel>  
  </UserControl>
```

RibbonGroup are shown with the Header but without the images, and the separate Image are shown itself. So maybe there are now any suggestions what goes wrong?

**EDIT2:**
If i step into with Snoop, the RibbonButtons and their corresponding images are present.

**EDIT3:**
I tried another way with resources, but same problem as above..
How it looks, when i have the RibbonTab in the resource/UserControl:
http://s12.postimg.org/lpposl48t/DLL_Ribbon_Tab_fail_part.png

How it looks, when i have the RibbonGroup in the resource/UserControl:
http://s12.postimg.org/oiiwcm4l9/DLL_Ribbon_Group_fail_part.png

Comment: Maybe there is anybody with an workaround, should i provide methods in the codebehind of the main window? (But then the goal to keep the view in xaml won't longer given.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research i found this from Ben Barefield:

http://www.benbarefield.com/blog/2011/03/04/ribbon-tab-definition-on-usercontrol/

He use a trick and move the ribbontab into a resourcedictionary.
Works well, but i also wanted to add some click events to this ribbontab (with view specific actions....) so i decided to fall back to the usercontrol.

The trick is, to detach the ribbontab from the usercontrol before adding it to the other control.

In detail:

add this methods to the usercontrol codebehind:

```
    private void AttachTabToRibbon(RibbonTab tab)
    {
        Ribbon Ribbon = null;
        Ribbon = getRibbon();
        if (Ribbon == null)
            return;
        Ribbon.Items.Add(tab);
    }

    private Ribbon getRibbon()
    {
        var control = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(this);
        Ribbon Ribbon = null;
        while (control != null && Ribbon == null)
        {
            var numberOfChildren = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChildren; ++i)
            {
                var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
                if (child is Ribbon)
                {
                    Ribbon = child as Ribbon;
                    return Ribbon;
                }
            }
            control = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(control);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void userControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Ribbon ribbonMenu = (Ribbon)this.FindName("ribbon");
        RibbonTab ribbonTabAdminInterface = (RibbonTab)this.FindName("ribbonTab");
        ribbonMenu.Items.Remove(ribbonTab);
        ucStackPanel.Children.Remove(ribbonMenu);
        AttachTabToRibbon(ribbonTab);
    }
```

furthermore call the userControl_Loaded:

```
<UserControl ...
             Loaded="userControl_Loaded"
>
<StackPanel x:Name="ucStackPanel">
    <Ribbon x:Name="ribbon" >
        <Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <RibbonApplicationMenu
            </RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <RibbonTab x:Name="ribbonTab"/>
        ...
     </Ribbon>
     ...
</StackPanel>
```